Why do we need type annotation in a Swift propertyWrapper?
Consider this @propertyWrapper:
@propertyWrapper struct Capitalized {
    var wrappedValue: String {
        didSet { wrappedValue = wrappedValue.capitalized }
    }
    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue.capitalized
    }
}

Using it this way:
struct User {
    @Capitalized var userName: String
}

My question is:
Why do I need to specify a type annotation with the property userName. Isn't the compiler smart enough to deduce that since the wrappedValue of @Capitalized type is String, the property userName can only be of type String.
If I omit the type annotation, I get a compiler error:

Type annotation missing in pattern


There are plenty of cases where types could be inferred (e.g. arguments of functions, return values, stored properties based on how they're initialized in the init, etc.). It's useful to force their existence are some places, both for human readability, and for increasing compilation speed. Some languages like Haskell have "global" type inference, but even in Haskell, optional type annotations are often specified for human readability.

I definitely agree that it can be better to provide a type annotation for clarity. But it's not actually required for property wrappers. SwiftUI's @Environment is generally written without a type annotation, for example. The diagnostic is just confusing here.

The diagnostic here is poor and doesn't point you to the actual issue. The problem is that @Capitalized with no assignment translates into Capitalized(), and there is no such initializer. You can fix this by providing a default initializer:
@propertyWrapper struct Capitalized {
    ...

    init() { self.init(wrappedValue: "") }
}

With this, your struct is fine:
struct User {
    @Capitalized var userName
}

Without the default init(), the following would also be fine, since it calls Capitalized(wrappedValue:):
struct User {
    @Capitalized var userName = "bob"
}

